# Circular navigation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

i have a view controller (A) that contains 2 buttons which pushes view to 2 other view controllers (B and C). The view controller B can push view to the view controller C and the view controller C can also push view to the view controller B. I have a circular navigation. All view controllers have their own navigation controller. I use ARC.
How can i deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is going to be more of a user experience issue than a technical one, particularly if each of these controllers has a separate navigation controller.  If you used a unified navigation controller to manage this stack, you could conceivably perform some operations on its `viewControllers` property "behind the user's back" to alter the stack so that you could be more explicit about what view was popped off the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use only one `UINavigationController`. with that controller you set your `A` controller as its root controller. From that view controller you can push your 'B' or `C` controller with same navigation controller by calling `[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourDesiredViewController animated:YES];`. But when you are that `yourDesiredViewController` and you are pushing another `viewController` from here there may be chance that you have came from the same `viewController` and there will be same `viewControllers` in your `navigationController` stack. so for avoiding this you can do this on your `secondViewController` (B) or (C)

```
//If the user has chosen to add new user then the viewcontroller will be popped....
for (UIViewController *aVC in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
    if ([aVC isKindOfClass:[DesiredViewController class]])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:aVC animated:YES];
        return;
    }
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourDesiredViewController animated:YES];
```

This will pop you to `yourDesiredViewController` if it is already present there or it will push `yourDesiredViewController` coz it is not in your stack. Do it on your `B` and `C` controller.